# Mobile not picking up CSS

Tags: html, css, drupal, mobile

I am developing a mobile version of a large site I've just done.
The menu jQuery Accordion as it's a pretty hefty navigation.

Normally I use Chrome and override the device agent and device metrics to work on the mobile.

I've styled my menu, and the nested `<ul>` for the sub-menus and it all looks perfectly fine.
For some reason though, on Chrome and Firefox on Android, and on the iPhone the nested lists don't pick up the styles at all. If I target a specific `<li>` then it will pick up the styles, but just not on the `<ul>`.

The parent `<ul>` are styled fine.

I've tried going from `html>body>blah>blah>ul#XXXX` but just doesn't work.

Anyone have any ideas why this might be?

Comment: please include your css and some html

Comment: That'll take a while.
The HTML is 4895 characters too long to enter here. It's a MASSIVE list.
Can't send a link as site in dev, so client would not be happy.
As I said, it works great if I view the mobile theme in Chrome on the desktop, it's just the nested UL styles that are not working on mobile, so the HTML/CSS is sound, it's just an issue woth the mobile browsers.

Comment: I'm guessing blind here, but my guess is that with the nested lists, you may have some interference with selectors like `ul li`. Because any `li` in the inner `ul` is also a descendant of the outer `ul`. So if I'm right, changing all `ul li` to `ul > li` might help.

Comment: I fixed it in the end. Each sub-menu list has it's own ID, which is what I was using as a selector. There is an overarching class for each list too, so I tried that instead. Boom. Works perfectly. No idea why it didn't like the ID though. Cheers for replying though @MrLister

Comment: Maybe the IDs were misspelled? Upper/lowercase mismatch, illegal characters, invisible pitfalls like Greek "ο"s etc.